# Sort Dropdown List Value From Database In Alphabetical Order

Tags: php, html, mysql, sorting, html-select

I'm able to populate my dropdown list with the values in my database. However, the list is unsorted and hectic due to large values. How can I have this list sorted in alphabetical order when the user clicks on the dropdown? My code is below.

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label">Employee Name</label>
 <select id="uni_name_drpdwn" class="form-control custom-select" name="emid" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1" value="" required>
    
<?php foreach($allemployees as $value): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $value->em_id ?>"><?php echo $value->first_name.' '.$value->last_name ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean in SQL? `SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY field_name ASC` or `DESC`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but no. I mean the data that is displayed to the user. The dropdown list is of Employee Names.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, why would you NOT do this in MySQL then just get the data sorted? Who wouldn't do this instead? Your code would begin to work as is.

Comment: I have it sorted using **SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY field_name ASC** which works everywhere else except in the DropDown List.

Answer (score 1):

```php
usort(
    $allemployees,
    fn($a, $b) => "$a->first_name $a->last_name" <=> "$b->first_name $b->last_name"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can assign an id to the list and in a js file you can select it by id and add sort(). For example:

     function ordenarListaDesplegable() {
            var selectElement = document.getElementById("miListaDesplegable");
            var options = selectElement.options;
            
            var arr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
              arr.push(options[i].text);
            }
            
            arr.sort();
            
            for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
              options[j].text = arr[j];
              options[j].value = "valor" + (j + 1);
            }
          }
          var miListaDesplegable = document.getElementById("miListaDesplegable");
          miListaDesplegable.addEventListener("click", ordenarListaDesplegable);
```

Comment: This definitely worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your dropdown `select` items directly in your SQL query using an `ORDER BY` clause:

```php
$allemployees = $db->query("SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY first_name, last_name ASC")->fetchAll();
```

This will sort your employees first by `first_name`, then by `last_name`, both in **ascending order**.

Your HTML/PHP code for the dropdown `select` doesn't change:

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label">Employee Name</label>
 <select id="uni_name_drpdwn" class="form-control custom-select" name="emid" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1" value="" required>
    
<?php foreach($allemployees as $value): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $value->em_id ?>"><?php echo $value->first_name.' '.$value->last_name ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</div>
```